# How to access List<> array inside the the activity java class from BaseAdapter class

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-popupwindow

I am creating a pop up menu dynamically, where the items will be populated from the web service.

The situation is, the parsing has been in the `MainActivity.java`, but the Pop up menu is inside the `BaseAdapter.java` class. I am adding all the menu items inside an array inside the `MainActivity.java`.Please refer the code below:

```
try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(menuItemsResponse.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String strMenuItemNames = object.getString("Name");

        listMenuItems.add(strMenuItemNames);
                }

     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

I am adding items inside `List<String> listMenuItems` with `listMenuItems.add(strMenuItemNames)`.

Now, I want to access this `listMenuitems` from BaseAdapter class. Below is my code for Pop Up menu inside `getView()` method in BaseAdapter class:

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(activity, imgDropDown);
popupMenu.getMenu().add()  // array to be added here


popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener({
   // on click events for each item
});
```

Anyone with solutions please respond.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is a method called getItem(int position) you can return same instance from this method and called adapter.getItem(<SelectedPosition>).

Answer (score 0):

**1.Add the list information you need to use in the construction method .**

```
List<String> listMenuItems;
public MyAdapter(List<String> listMenuItems, Context context) {
   ...
}
```

**2.use it in your code .**

```
popupMenu.getMenu().add(listMenuItems.get(position));
```

Try this .

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<String> listMenuItems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(List<String> listMenuItems, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listMenuItems = listMenuItems;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
        ...

        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(activity, imgDropDown);
        // edited here 
        popupMenu.getMenu().add(listMenuItems.get(position));  // array to be added here
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener({
                // on click events for each item
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try @GRK 's answer .

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface like below

```
interface MenuItemProvider {
     getMenuItems(); // add parameters, returntype based on your need.
}
```

Activity implements this interface and implements getMenuItems() method by returning the listItems that are prepared in activity.

Now, your adapter should have a setter method to set this interface like below.

```
class yourActivity extends <> implements MenuItemProvider {

// other implementation.

// pass this implementation to your base adapter.
baseadapterinstance.setMenuItemProvider(this);


getMenuItems(){
 // return list items.
}



    }


/*** BaseAdpater class. ***/
private MenuItemProvider menuItemProviderImpl;

void setMenuItemProvider(MenuItemProvider menuItemProviderImpl){
this. menuItemProviderImpl = menuItemProviderImpl;
}

// when you need to get the list, call 
menuItemProviderImpl.getMenuItems();
```

Hope this helps!!